# Do I need a subfloor or a Dricore subfloor panels on concrete (basement) for ceramic tile?

Tags: concrete, basement, floor, subfloor

I'm trying to do the most intelligent, yet cost efficient method to tiling by concrete basement floor.  On some sites, it states to use a subfloor, with the underlayment.  Others it states to just tile over the concrete, with an underlayment.  I DID purchase some of the Dricore panels, but I'm not sure if using them will be a benefit or just an expensive, no value added addition?  I have no idea the best way to go about this.  HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the Dricore panels!! It is a great product, but not for tile installs.

If you want the best installation, go directly over the floor with an [anti-fracture](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Schluter-Systems-Ditra-54-sq-ft-Orange-Plastic-Waterproofing-Tile-Membrane/3580144?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-Flooring-_-GroutMortarAndSealers-_-3580144:Schluter_Systems&CAWELAID=&kpid=3580144&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=1631&k_clickID=006286c3-9a97-4ae8-8b0b-afdbf3d76473&gclid=Cj0KCQjw-uzVBRDkARIsALkZAdn4iwVC7fo1iTih4hBW-zLRrNN6vBVT-aFqcspw9pWcwm1yPp0ttosaAiggEALw_wcB) membrane and tile directly over that. Many big box stores will carry one brand or another that will do the job. If the floor has been around for many years and there are no cracks where you wish to lay tile, then in my opinion, you will not need the anti-fracture membrane either, go directly over the concrete.